# Node + Express get username (req.user undefined)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to add authentication to a part of my site that will grant access to only certain users here:

```
router.get("/file/:myFile", function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user) //undefined. Ideally I could just req.user.username and be set.
    var dirFile = __dirname + "/file/" + req.params.myFile;
    fs.readFile(dirFile, function (err,data){
        if(err) {console.log(err);}
        res.contentType("application/pdf");
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

I believe the issue is that in my login function, I'm just returning a json web token, so all the authentication and client information is staying on the client side of things. My login function:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
    if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
        return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
        }

    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
        if(err){ return next(err); }

        if(user){
            return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});
        } else {
            return res.status(401).json(info);
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

This works great if I'm doing a one page application and I can just handle requests client side, but since I'm trying to serve a PDF I'm not sure how else to handle this.

Comment: If you are using JWT, couldn't you just make the query with the JWT and check it's valid on express?

Comment: Isn't the token stored on the client though? How would I check that?

Comment: I'm not too sure, might not be a good idea to send the token as a query string. Could you not set the JWT to a cookie and then check the cookie and verify the token on the request?